# I can't read from a file

Tags: c++, file-handling, file-read

I wrote a code to make "text1.txt" file. It worked correctly, then I've been trying to read from the file, but every time `is_open()` function doesn't return true. Even so I copied other codes in the way exactly they are in different compilers, but it never works. How will I solve this:(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream file1("text1.txt");
    string str;
    if(file1.is_open()){
        while(getline( file1, str)){
        cout<<str;
        }
    }
    else
        cout<<"the file is not open"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try a full file path, e.g. `ifstream file1("/users/phidan/home/text1.txt");`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Phidan, thank you for posting the code. Next time try giving a more descriptive title to your question, It will help other users with the same question find your post easier.

Answer (score 1):

How are you running your program?

The most common cause of this I've seen is that you're running your program inside an IDE (like Visual Studio), and your current directory isn't where you think it is.

Try putting in the full path to the file and see if your problem disappears.

Comment: I use eclipse. And it gives an error when I put in the full location of the file,.

Comment: Try forward slashes.